# SQL Server 2012 Integration Services failed when connecting thru SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I had recently installed SQL server 2012 and I used mostly the default settings.  Database works fine and I can happily connect using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) but when I connect to the Integration Services Server I get this message

> Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer
>   "localhost" failed with the following error: "Access is denied."
>
> By default, only administrators have access to the Integration
>   Services service. On Windows Vista and later, the process must be
>   running with administrative privileges in order to connect to the
>   Integration Services service. See the help topic for information on
>   how to configure access to the service.

here is the screenshot
[image]

I am not sure why but I am the domain admin and have full rights over the server.  Also why when I connect from my Desktop it can successfully connect, only if I connect from the server itself which gives me this issues. How do I fix this so that I can make SSMS on the server connect to its Integration Services instance.

Comment: To clarify: on your desktop, you can connect to ServerA and click the IS Catalog. RDC into ServerA, fire up SSMS and you cannot connect to the IS Catalog?

Comment: Also, while undoubtedly unrelated to your issue, [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35575) is available for SQL Server 2012

Comment: Yup you are correct if I connect using SSMS to ServerA from Workstation it works, but if I RDC into ServerA and connect using SSMS to ServerA then I get that error message above

Comment: Is UAC running on ServerA?

Comment: Can you answer this below so I can give you the check! I tried to run the SSMS as admin and it works! You rock dude!

Comment: @nadeem's answer was 90% of what i needed. What I was missing is that I need to go to users & groups, select the group 'Distributed COM Users' and add the user.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As I understand it, User Access Control, or [UAC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), can basically intercept requests for your group membership so in this case, it appears it was preventing your membership getting passed to SQL Server.

Others have noted in their comments that you may still need to right click and run SSMS as an Administrator.

As noted by an astute observer "This is a quick-fix, not a real solution. People shouldn't just be running stuff as administrator. These security walls are in place for a reason" And I agree. UAC is designed to get Windows users into a [Principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) mindset - only escalate to a powerful account when required. The issue is that SSMS is known to not "play well" with UAC. As I see it, this leaves you with three options

- You can turn off UAC and get your work done
- Leave UAC on and tell your boss you are unable to work
- Write your own query tool that is not affected by UAC

Comment: Holy sh*t. Thanks. Read that and this. And stilll after switching off UAC, it is also necessary to launch SSMS through "Run As Administrator"!!!!

Comment: This is a quick-fix, not a real solution. People shouldn't just be running stuff as administrator. These security walls are in place for a reason.

Comment: @siride I agree it is a hack and I look forward to your answer that provides the true solution.

Comment: @billinkc: Nadeem's answer is what I did and it worked fine.

Answer (score 37):

Go to all programs Click on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 folder Right click on SQL Server Management Studio Click on Run as Administrator

This should take care of problem for now. (With this you need to always repeat the same process). To avoid this every time and for a more persistent solution you need to get permission(s). Please do the following process and you should be good.

In previous versions of SQL Server, by default when you installed SQL Server all users in the Users group had access to the Integration Services service. When you install the current release of SQL Server, users do not have access to the Integration Services service. The service is secure by default. After SQL Server is installed, the administrator must grant access to the service.

To grant access to the Integration Services service

1. Run Dcomcnfg.exe. Dcomcnfg.exe provides a user interface for modifying certain settings in the registry.
2. In the Component Services dialog, expand the Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config node.
3. Right-click Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 11.0, and then click Properties.
4. On the Security tab, click Edit in the Launch and Activation Permissions area.
5. Add users and assign appropriate permissions, and then click Ok.
6. Repeat steps 4 - 5 for Access Permissions.
7. Restart SQL Server Management Studio.
8. Restart the Integration Services Service.

*(Source MSDN)*

I hope this will help

Comment: This is the long term solution and should be voted up.

Comment: I followed these steps and even restarted the server. I still can't connect remotely.

Comment: I have found I can access SSIS service remote if I have a domain admin acct. But i can't connect remotely even though I have explicitly granted my login full privs following the above steps.

Comment: Yep, also for SQL 2016 Server Sp1 on Server 2012r2, look for " Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 13.0" instead .

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6236/connecting-to-integration-services-access-is-denied-in-sql-server-2016-or-2017/#:~:text=Right%2Dclick%20on%20it%20and%20choose%20%22Properties%22.&text=Here%20we%20should%20set%20%22Launch,%22Launch%20and%20Activation%20Permissions%22.&text=Hence%2C%20the%20problem%20is%20solved,using%20SQL%20Server%20Management%20Studio.

Comment: Dont forget to restart SSMS - Run AS Administrator, even after DCOM configurations!

Answer (score 7):

Right Click on the Sql Server Management Studio and select Run as Administrator and try to connect
if it is installed on the local instance

Answer (score 2):

You should check to see what user the SSIS Service is running under.  Go to Start > Run > Type "services.msc" and scroll down to the SQL Server Integration Services 11.0 entry.  Right click and check the properties to find out what user it's running under.  The second tab should be the LogOn tab.  Since you're just running on a local instance, you can set your user as the LogOn User account and SSIS will have the same permissions that you do.

Comment: That should be all OK because the service uses a domain account which have administrative privileges on the server meaning it is in the "Administrators" group

Comment: Anyways out of curiosity I tried your suggestion and run the service as my username, still got the same error

Comment: Worked like a charm. Once this change is made one needs to restart all SQL services.

Answer (score 0):

Lost a day of work on that problem. My package has a .NET script task to copy file from a shared network folder to a local folder and I was stuck with the "access denied" exception every time I tried to execute the package from the server (Through SQL Studio). The package works fine when running locally.

Tried many things picked up here and there and at the end of the day what worked is to create a Job (owner is sa) which execute the package as SSISExecutor.

I have to mention that the file on the network has read access for everyone, and that I still don't understand what was wrong.