# SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition setup for Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have just set up Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 Enterprise Edition on my machine and have checked to install the Reporting Service, and also the Integration Services package.

See the discovery report post-installation: [image: Discovery Report]

I have enabled the following ports:
2383, 2382, 4022, 1433, 1434, 135, 80, 443

My attempts to start/connect to the Integration Services have been futile. When I open Management Studio, I select Integration Services to connect but I get the following message (screenshot): [image: Error Screenshot]

Can somebody point me in the right direction so I can get started to using SSIS please?

**More information:**
I have 2 physical drives -- SSD (C:) and a HDD (D:). SQL Server is installed on D:, which Windows 7 is running on C:.

My user name belongs to or is part of the group of administrators. The Administrator account is disabled.

Comment: Have you started the SSMS "As Administrator"? As alternative, you can disable UAC. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941998/sql-server-2012-integration-services-failed-when-connecting-thru-ssms#

Comment: Does the service account which SSIS runs under have adequate permissions?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the dreaded DCOM permissions issue, ref:

http://sqlbuzz.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/connecting-to-the-integration-services-service-on-the-computer-mirrorstand-failed-with-the-following-error-access-is-denied/

Good luck!