# SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition - Unable to connect to SSIS Service

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have installed SQL Server 2012 Dev Edition in my laptop ( Personal Computer ) on Windows 8 OS.

I am able to log in to the SQL Server Management Studio, SSAS, SSRS.

I am not able to log into the SSIS. By default, SQL Window shows only the Windows Authentication. Windows Authentication should log into the SSIS Environment. But it is not allowing. And choosing the authentication mode is disabled.

[SQL Server 2012 Integration Services failed when connecting thru SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941998/sql-server-2012-integration-services-failed-when-connecting-thru-ssms)

There is a suggestion of downloading Service Pack 1.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35575#

But, Service Pack 1 has too many files to download. I am not sure which file to download.

I have attached the screenshot of the error. [image]

[image]

Comment: Are you running SSMS as administrator?

Comment: Yes, i am running SSMS as Admin

Comment: Server Name just try using `.` or `Localhost`

Comment: TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to localhost.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

Comment: @MuhammedAli , I tried. Using both . and localhost. Failed

Comment: Fire up `Sql Server Configuration Manager` --> `Sql Server Services` --> Look for `Sql Server Integration Services` see if you can find it there, if you can see it in the list then check for its `State` make sure it `Running`.

Comment: I see the SQL Server Integration Services running in the SQL Server Configuration Manager. Have attached the Image in the Original Post

Comment: @MuhammedAli, if you look into the Image,ServiceType is not displaying for SSIS.

Comment: try running management studio as admin usually this should work,alternatively give access to your self for MSDB database

Comment: @sam, i did running as admin.

Comment: May be this is what you have done but what i mean by try running as admin is right click on management studio and then click run as adminstrator