# Create Integration Services Catalog button missing in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssms, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to create an Integration Services Catalog on a company SQL Server in SSMS, but when I right click the Integration Services Catalog folder there is no option to create a catalog ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9XAg.png)). There is also no visible Catalog that already exists.

**I have tried**:

- Making sure I have sufficient permissions (I have the **db_owner** role)
- Checking if CLR Integration is enabled (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPtPU.png))
- Making sure Integration Services was installed as a feature on my (personal) SQL Server install (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VtVx.png))
- Checking if Integration Services is running in (my personal) Configuration Manager (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHXVy.png))
- [This Dcomcnfg permissions escalation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20391524/19671123)

The company SQL Server runs via virtual machine in Azure on build version 12.0.2000.8

My personal Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio's version info reads:

- SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18390.0
- SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) 16.100.46521.71
- Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 15.0.19714.0
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  10.0.19041.1
- Microsoft MSXML  3.0 6.0
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000
- Operating System 10.0.19043

Has anyone else had this issue or can suggest why it isn't possible for me to create a catalog?

Thanks

Comment: Has the integration services component been installed on the server VM?

Comment: *"The company SQL Server runs via virtual machine in Azure on build version 12.0.2000.8"* This doesn't sound like you are using Azure SQL Managed Instance, it sounds like you using a Azure SQL Database; you can't deploy SSIS packages to Azure SQL databases. If you need SSIS then you aren't using the correct product. The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9XAg.png) further cements this, as if you were using a Managed Instance on Azure you would be able to see a lot [more nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX2Nu.png) than those 3. and the version number would not be the one you've supplied.

Comment: Thanks both, I think @Larnu is correct, I will try to use an Azure defined method like the one in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-deploy-run-monitor-tutorial?view=azuresqldb-current) to deploy SSIS packages to our company server. If the question gets 2 upvotes I can select an answer - I don't have enough rep just yet.